# Ghostscript.Net преобразование изображений в PDF файл

Tags: c#, pdf, ghostscript

Пытаюсь при помощи Ghostscript.Net преобразовать набор изображений в один pdf файл. Сначала для проверки пробую преобразовать изображения при помощи gs следующей командой в командной строке:

`gswin32.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o out.pdf viewjpeg.ps -c "(test.jpg) viewJPEG showpage (test2.jpg) viewJPEG showpage"`

на выходе получаю pdf файл, содержащий две страницы с необходимыми изображениями, как и предполагалось.
Далее пытаюсь сделать тоже самое при помощи Ghostscript.NET(версия gs 9.26) в консольном приложении с использованием .NET Framework 4.0, ОС Win7:

```
...
string viewjpeg = File.ReadAllText("viewjpeg.ps");
using (GhostscriptProcessor processor = new GhostscriptProcessor(gvi))
                {
                    List<string> switches = new List<string>();
                    switches.Add("-dBATCH");
                    switches.Add("-sDEVICE=pdfwrite");
                    switches.Add("-o out.pdf");
                    switches.Add(viewjpeg);
                    switches.Add("-c (test.jpg) viewJPEG showpage (test2.jpg) viewJPEG showpage");

                    try
                    {
                        processor.StartProcessing(switches.ToArray(), null);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
```

При выполнении программы получаю ошибку:
`An error occured when call to 'gsapi_init_with_args' is made: -100`

В чём может быть проблема?

При этом сам gs установлен корректно, в этом же приложении успешно выполняется разбиение pdf файла на изображения. Файлы test.jpg и test2.jpg располагаются в одной директории с исполняемым файлом.
Так же пробовал:
`switches.Add("-c \"(test.jpg) viewJPEG showpage (test2.jpg) viewJPEG showpage\"");`

Comment: `switches.Add(viewjpeg);` вместо этого должно быть `switches.Add("viewjpeg.ps");` - не?

Comment: если сделать так, то он просто выведет пустой pdf документ